# Coding in Objective-C 2.0 screencasts?

Tags: objective-c

Has anyone used the Pragmatic Programmers screencast series [Coding in Objective-C 2.0](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdobjc/coding-in-objective-c-2-0)?

They look good, but I don't know if I could get just as much value out of a text book or other web links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bought both screen casts. I'm neither a starving student nor a starving out of work developer, so $5 is effectively free.

A screen cast can cover material fairly quickly because there's no need to stop and describe what's going on; the viewer gets to watch every step. There's none of the awkwardness you find in books that have to use words to describe every step in great detail.

So yes, I found them to be worth the $5 and I'll buy any more that come out.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for, someone who had watched them.

Comment: I do have them as well, very good tutorials, lot's of explanation not only on how to do stuff but why. :)

Answer (score 0):

At $5.00 a video your not going to find "as much value out of a  text book" books would cover a lot more information though.

edit:

I haven't watched the screen casts, but If you have programming expereinece, getting a book (maybe even their book?) would be what I'd recomend instead. By just looking at the topics covered and the time given I can't see the screen casts (the two that are available I mean) going into that much detail

Comment: I guess I should have asked if it is worth the $5.00.